# Regex not working from JavsScript function - why?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple JS function for validating email like this (the more complicated snippet wasn't working so I commented it out and simplified what I have, but it still doesn't work):

```js
    function validateEmail(email) {
    //var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    //return re.test(email);
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}

console.log(`TESTING THE VALIDATE FUNCTION - GMAIL@GMAIL.COM RETURNS: ${validateEmail("gmail@gmail.com")}`);
```

When I run this in the console it works fine. When I run this from my code (A/B testing tool) it returns false every time even though I am expecting true. I feel like I need to bang my head against the wall because I can't figure it out. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: /\w+@\w+\.\w+/;

Comment: If it works in the console maybe it's not the regex but the way your A/B tools checks it. do you know what method it uses to matchs the regex ?

Comment: Maybe add more to the log message, so you can see the input string. Or log it from within the `validateEmail` function so that it always shows you what it's receiving. This should help you figure out why it's not working. As @Nicolas said, with this code working fine, it's almost certain to be the A/B testing you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that the tool I use automatically escaped some characters in my regex string. As a result my string was not being evaluated correctly. For those interested, the A/B testing tool I use is SiteSpect.